# django.contrib.admin - why is i18n used in template?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there any reason to have `app.name` inside a `blocktrans` tag in [app_index](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/app_index.html) template from django admin app?

```
{% for app in app_list %}
{% blocktrans with app.name as name %}{{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
{% endfor %}
```

As far as I can see, the result would always be similiar to result of this:

```
{% for app in app_list %}
{{ app.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you *can* specify the `app_label` on a model in its `Meta` class, and presumably that custom value could employ `ugettext` to translate it for different languages. That's a pretty odd scenario, though, and would most likely be problematic in practice.

Most likely the Django devs did it just to future proof and cover edge-case scenarios. It doesn't *hurt* to pass something through `blocktrans`. If there's no translation, it'll simply return the value as is, and it's safer to not make presumptions about what should or should not be translated.

Answer (score 0):

Found Django internationalization and localization [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-i18n/vc2vQzv80UQ/MXQTWcXoSXIJ). I am pasting relevant answer from Django developer here:

> I agree with your conclusion. The "blocktrans" tag is simply being
>   used inappropriately here. It's a good tag for translating essentially
>   static template content. What it doesn't do it look inside the
>   variables it substitutes, so is appropriate where the translation
>   works regardless of the variable content. It appears particularly
>   severe in this case because the blocktrans section *only* includes a
>   variable replacement.